# ag-grid-angular tests with Jest fail with error "Class constructor VanillaFrameworkOverrides cannot be invoked without 'new'"

Tags: angular, jestjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

After upgrading to the latest major version of [ag-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-community), the tests with Jest fail with the following error.

`TypeError: Class constructor VanillaFrameworkOverrides cannot be invoked without 'new'`

I have a [repo](https://github.com/GeorgianStan/angular-ag-grid) with a simple table, where this can be visible.
The steps to reproduce are the following:

Download the repo and run the following commands:

1. `npm i`
2. `npx nx serve angular-ag-grid` (This will open the app and the table will be visible. Here all works as expected.)
3. `npx nx test angular-ag-grid` (This will run the unit test with Jest and it will **crash**.).